# Authorization not working, It does not forbidden users to access my actions in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, jwt

In start up

ConfigureServices function I add this

```
         services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
   {
       jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
       {
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

           ValidateIssuer = false,
           ValidateAudience = false
       };
   });
```

then in Configure function I added this

```
  app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
```

and I added this line to my API

```
[Authorize]
```

but it give user to allow that function, what is my mistake? which part of auth I forget to add my code?

Comment: Well, you have not specified an Authority to JWT Bearer authentication. Also, where in your middleware pipeline are Authentication and Authorization? They must be between Routing and Endpoints.

Comment: can you give me any usefull document link please?What do you mean with middleware?is that login?If yes I didn't call login,I call get,I want get forbidden warning because I didn't login that service